# Firebase uploadBytes call returning 403 despite user authorized

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, firebase-security

This is my current code:

```
async newCollectionRequest({ commit }, data) {
  try {
    console.log(data);
    const location = `/pending-images/${data.collectionName}/${data.image.name}`;
    console.log(location);

    const storage = getStorage();
    const storageRef = ref(storage, location);

    // 'file' comes from the Blob or File API
    await uploadBytes(storageRef, data.image);
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error.message;
  }
},
```

It seems to be working, but only in that I'm getting a 403 response when attempting to upload the image. I'm unsure why I'm getting a 403 in the first place though as I've implemented authentication on the app, and I've confirmed the user is logged in when trying to take this action. This is my firebase rule:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is resulting in a 403 error

Comment: Since you are writing an `async` function, don't you want to `await` the result of `uploadBytes` instead of using `then`?

Comment: honestly, i didn't think it mattered yet. this is technically a rough draft, i usually go back and correct for junk writing like that afterwards. will clean that up right away though

Comment: Using await will have a very different effect on this function than using then. Right now, your function will return true before the upload is complete.

Comment: it didn't solve the 403, unfortunately. effectively it is the same behavior - except i see now what you mean. you're totally right about that bug, i hadn't noticed it yet since the function's return isn't hooked up to anything yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have posted a `firestore.rules` file. You are using Firebase storage. You must create a `storage.rules` file in the root of your Firebase project (the same place you have your `firestore.rules` file) and add something like:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This will grant full read/write access to any authenticated user. You can [read more about storage rules here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security).

Comment: I might need a bit of hand holding to figure this out. I'm using the cloud.firestore part for authentication. When i remove that, the auth stops working. So i tried adding the firebase.storage rule in addition to the cloud.firestore rule, and while that got the auth working, i'm still getting a 403 response despite those rules being present now. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your authentication will work independently of any of these files. Then there is a firestore.rules file that guards access to firestore, storage.rules to guard access to storage, database.rules for realtime database. You likely want a firestore.rules file AND a storage.rules file. 

If you're using the emulator, these files will be loaded locally.

If you are testing live, you'll need to do a `firebase deploy` or update the rules in the web console.

Comment: I'm using the web console. I just pasted both in, but that appears to be the incorrect approach. I don't see what would be correct either. I was mistaken earlier though, it wasn't giving me the same 403 error, it was failing the post for a cors error, so maybe there is progress? I'm not sure. It seems like there may be multiple things wrong with my set up currently.

Comment: aha! So what was wrong with my account was that I hadn't activated Storage yet. I didn't understand that the files that you're referring to have equivalents on the web interface, and those products have to each be individually activated before you can use them. I totally didn't understand that part, but once I figured it out, everything started working. This is absolutely the correct answer, thank you so much!